# getting a String sequence from an ascii sequence in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a java project for the RSA cryptography, but I have a problem in converting a long ASCII sequence to a String sequence, for the last part for getting the plainText in cryptography.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String hj = w2.getText();
    String longue;
    BigInteger rg, tfd;
    String gh = "";
    String e = "", rtyu = "", hjk = "";
    longue = String.valueOf(h);
    int kl = longue.length();
    int jh = hj.length();
    int nb = jh / (kl);
    int gc = jh - (kl) * nb;
    for (int uy = 0; uy < nb; uy++) {
        rg = new BigInteger(hj.substring((uy * (kl)), ((uy + 1) * ((kl)))));
        tfd = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(rg.modPow(des, h)));

        e+= String.valueOf(tfd);
    }
    jTextArea1.setText(e);
    byte[] byt;
    byt = e.getBytes();
```

...
    }

I want to know what I can do after that for converting a e to its value in characters?

Example: I want to convert this ASCII sequence 656667 to characters for getting the value "ABC",

Comment: Here's an advice for future questions and your coding style in general. Try to make your variables descriptive of what they store for better readability and debugging.

Comment: `gh` is your ASCII sequence? So the above code doesn't relate to the question in any way right?

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, what u said about gh is true, i edited the code, it's the variable  e  not gh. Thank you so much Zingerella

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is well-formed, this java 8 solution will work for you:

```
String unconverted = "656667";

String converted = IntStream.range(0, unconverted.length() / 2)
    .map(i -> Integer.parseInt(unconverted.substring(i * 2, (i * 2) + 2)))
    .collect(
        StringBuilder::new,
        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
        StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();
```